# Error while creating the Test Project: The template file for selected project type is missing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

Has anyone encountered the following problem:

when I try to create unittests in VS (by using context menu "Create Unit Tests..." for the class ), it returns an exception:

"The following error occurred while creating the Test Project.
The template file for selected project type is missing."

I checked, the folder Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Test\1033 already contains TestProject.zip

Just in case I tried to run devenv /installvstemplates and devenv /resetsettings. Didn't help.

Any ideas?